# Orientation stops after performing some action

Tags: ios, swift3, orientation, xcode8

In my application, there is a home view which I set as root view controller after performing some actions. After then my application orientation stops but ios native components works on changing orientation i.e. my app does not change its orientation but if there is keypad present then only keypad will change its orientation. I am not locking the orientation in my app and gave all four orientation supports for whole app.
[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLsFK.png)
**Code:**

```
let testViewController: MyHomeViewController = MyHomeViewController(nibName: "MyHomeViewController", bundle: nil) 
APP_DELEGATE.rootNavigationController?.viewControllers = [testViewController] 
UIView.transition(with: APP_DELEGATE.window!, duration: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
    () -> Void in APP_DELEGATE.window!.rootViewController = APP_DELEGATE.rootNavigationController 
    }) { (completion) -> Void in}
```

Comment: put some code .

Comment: let testViewController: MyHomeViewController = MyHomeViewController(nibName: "MyHomeViewController", bundle: nil)
        APP_DELEGATE.rootNavigationController?.viewControllers = [testViewController]
        UIView.transition(with: APP_DELEGATE.window!, duration: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve, animations: { () -> Void in
            APP_DELEGATE.window!.rootViewController = APP_DELEGATE.rootNavigationController
        }) { (completion) -> Void in}

Comment: after this my app orientation do not work but for native components it works.

Comment: viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) did not called on rotation.

Comment: @MohitMangla add code in question and not comment